# Is there an official XML Schema (xsd) for EDI X12 856?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, x12

I am still fairly new to EDI, and learning it on a new job. We are using BizTalk for our EDI solution, and are converting the incoming EDI file into XML. I was having problems with a file from a new vendor, and at first thought the file might be incorrect. I have since learned that the file is correct, but our current XML schema is home grown, and would basically need to be tailored to accept this 856. I guess some of the data being passed in is more then what our usual vendors pass to us (still valid according to EDI X12 856 though).

While I could do this, it seems like the real answer is getting an xsd file for the actual EDI spec. It seems like with such a standardized format it should already exist. Does anyone know if such a thing is available?

UPDATE: It turns out there is a built in EDI mapping capability that is done in the pipeline through the "EDI Disassembler" component. This converts to a standardized BizTalk EDI schema and is working correctly. Apparently our code then converts that XML into our own XML schema. There is definitely room to improve, but I think the information on schema standards is what I am looking for at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question. I'm assuming BizTalk has EDI mapping capabilities, and that you've used it to map elements of the EDI format to your XML tags. If they're sending a segment that's not in your schema, doesn't the mapper ignore it?

Assuming the sender is using XML EDI rather than binary EDI, there are schemas available. http://www.x12.org/ has a link to them (requires JavaScript), but you have to register. I'm used to paying for everything EDI-related (documentation, translation, testing, etc.) so you may have to purchase them.

Here's an additional link I found to a commercial product: [stylusstudio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/edi/X12_validate.html)

EDIT: Direct link: http://xml.x12.org/

Comment: Hey Will, thanks for taking the time to answer. It spurred me to take a closer look at what was going on. I added more information to the question.

I think the issue with our own schema is our problem, and just bad code that needs to be fixed. The question was for information on an official XSD schema, and you answered that. Also I found that the BizTalk installation contains them as well, and can be found by running this self inflating zip:

drive:\Program Files\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2009\XSD_Schema\EDI\MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates.exe

Comment: I didn't know BizTalk came with them. It makes sense, for validation. Thanks! And yeah, customers/vendors are always sending stuff in weird segments that you're not expecting. The two parties in an EDI transaction always have to agree on the standards/segments that they're using. You (hopefully) can get a copy of the subset they're using from your business partner (whoever's sending the 856).

Comment: Thanks again Will for you help. As I continue to wrap my head around EDI I think there are a lot of things we could be doing better. One step at a time though, or one refactor :)

Comment: NP. Seems like a number of people are going to cXML these days in certain circles (like punchouts).
http://www.cxml.org/prnews/faq.cfm

Comment: Hello Andrew, I am looking for exactly what you were looking for in 2009(when this question was asked). Looking up Google, I still don't see anything related to standard XSD for EDI Specs like 810. It seems most of the standard definitions are protected by X12.org as IPR and there is a $530 fees (individual) to get to these schemas/definitions. Were you able to find anything in the open domain?